# MEAN stack and bootstrap / bower issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, bower, mean-stack

I'm currently exploring new ways to develop and have come across the MEAN stack, which can be found here - http://mean.io/#!/

I have installed Mongo, Node (plus npm etc...) and gone through all the steps stated on the website. The issue comes when I execute grunt (or even node server.js) and open the webpage - terminal displays the following:

> Error: ENOENT, open '/Users/xxx/myApp/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'

First problem is, bower_components directory doesn't actually exist! I'm assuming this is probably the first point of call, however I'm not totally sure where to start in troubleshooting this (I'm new to bower).

Does anyone have any experience with MEAN stack and/or how to resolve the issue with bootstrap / bower_components directory?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Note that bower will *not run* if you are logged in as root.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like you haven't installed bower, and as a result of that not installed bootstrap through bower.

Install Bower

```
$ npm install -g bower
```

Install bootstrap via bower

```
$ bower install bootstrap
```

You can read more about it their [website](http://bower.io/). And also search for bower packages [here](http://bower.io/search/). Since you're using angular you might wanna download angular-bootstrap as well.

## UPDATE

What bower provides is a package manager for client-side modules. Similar to npm, with the difference that npm also provides backend-/nodejs-modules.

**If you're using `mean.io`**  your project will be prepared with a file called `bower.json` and another one called `package.json` which specifies the dependencies in your project. To install these, start off by getting your node.js dependencies:

```
$ npm install
```

If you want bower to be installed globally, use:

```
$ npm install -g bower
```

Then install your bower dependencies

```
$ bower install
```

And now you should be good to go.

### You can also add bower manually

or if you want to **`create your mean project from scratch`**

Install Bower

```
$ npm install -g bower
```

Install bootstrap via bower

```
$ bower install bootstrap
```

### Save your dependencies

If you want to create bower.json to save your dependencies:

```
$ bower init
```

and follow the instructions provided in the console.

Now when you install new bower packages you use `--save` and bower will add the dependency to your bower.json.

```
$ bower install bootstrap --save
```

Comment: I would like to add that you should run `bower install` in the project route and it should install all the bower dependencies for you